# How to filter WebGrid in MVC using partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am unable to refresh my WebGrid. I want to search based on a string filter using stored procedure. In controller, My list gets updated for a given string filter. But I am unable to pass this data to UI via ajax.
If anyone can help me please?

index.cshtml:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function search(searchby) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/Home/searchCPW",
                    data: { search: searchby, action: 'Client' },
                    datatype: "json",
                    traditional: true,
                    done: function (data) {
                        alert('Done');
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        // debugger
                        if (data == "No Record Found") {
                            alert('No Record Found');
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#gridContent").html(response);
                            $('#search').val(searchby);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

    </script>
 @Html.TextBox("txtbx1", "", new { onkeyup = "search($(this).val());", id = "#search" })
       @{
        Html.RenderPartial("_SearchCPW",Model);
    }
```

Controller function:

```
 public ActionResult searchCPW(string search,string action)
    {
        List<p_search_ccpw_CPW> lstSearchModel = new List<p_search_ccpw_CPW>();
        List<p_search_ccpw_CPW> lstSearchMasters = entities.p_search_ccpw_CPW("", search, action).ToList();
        lstSearchMasters.ForEach(x =>
        {
            p_search_ccpw_CPW stuModel = new p_search_ccpw_CPW();
            stuModel.Name = x.Name;
            stuModel.ID = x.ID;
            lstSearchModel.Add(stuModel);
        });
        if (lstSearchModel.Count > 0)
        {
            return View("_SearchCPW", lstSearchModel);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("No Record Found");
        }
    }
```

Partial view:_SearchCPW

```
@model   IEnumerable<TestingGrid.p_search_ccpw_CPW>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_SearchCPW";
}
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5,
    selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
}

@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
    headerStyle: "header",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    selectedRowStyle: "select",
    columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("ID", " ID"),
    grid.Column("Name", "Name")))
```

Comment: Are you able to debug the controller action when you make an AJAX request to it?

Comment: In controler i got the results, after returning partial view it didn't come to the ajax success  block